# bad syntax (multiple expressions after identifier)

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I am writing a function, `try-weak-cues`, to select a response from a large set of responses. This program is essentially a conversation with the user.

```
(define try-weak-cues
        (lambda (sentence context)
        (define helper
           (lambda(list-of-pairs)
          (define helper2
            (lambda(list-of-pairs context)
              (cond((null? list-of-pairs)
                  (cond((null? list-of-pairs) '())
                       ((any-good-fragments?(cue-part(car list-of-pairs))sentence) (helper2(cdr(car list-of-pairs))context))
                        (else(helper(cdr list-of-pairs)))))))))
                       (helper *weak-cues*))))
```

Below is the list of responses that the function is supposed to pull from:

```
 (define *weak-cues*
  '( ( ((who) (whos) (who is))
       ((first-base)
           ((thats right) (exactly) (you got it)
        (right on) (now youve got it)))
       ((second-base third-base)
           ((no whos on first) (whos on first) (first base))) )
     ( ((what) (whats) (what is))
       ((first-base third-base)
       ((hes on second) (i told you whats on second)))
       ((second-base)
       ((right) (sure) (you got it right))) )
     ( ((whats the name))
       ((first-base third-base)
       ((no whats the name of the guy on second)
        (whats the name of the second baseman)))
       ((second-base)
    ((now youre talking) (you got it))))
   ))
```

The error:

> define: bad syntax (multiple expressions after identifier) in: (define
>   helper (lambda (list-of-pairs) (define helper2 (lambda (list-of-pairs
>   context) (cond ((null? list-of-pairs) (cond ((null? list-of-pairs)
>   (quote ())) ((any-good-fragments? (cue-part (car list-of-pairs))
>   sentence) (helper2 (cdr (car list-of-pairs)) context)) (else (helper
>   (cdr list-of-pairs))))))))) (helper *weak-cues*))

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that, when you define an internal procedure inside the body of a `lambda`, you *have to* write an expression after the definition, typically calling the internal procedure. For example, this is wrong:

```
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    (define g
      (lambda (y)
        <body 1>))))
```

But this is correct, notice how after the inner `lambda` definition there's a `<body 2>` part:

```
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    (define g
      (lambda (y)
        <body 1>))
    <body 2>))
```

Also, your code will be much easier to debug if you avoid this style of procedure definition:

```
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    <body>))
```

It'll be shorter and clearer like this:

```
(define (f x)
  <body>)
```

Now, back to your code. After fixing the formatting and switching to the shorter procedure definition syntax, your code will look like this:

```
(define (try-weak-cues sentence context)
  (define (helper list-of-pairs)
    (define (helper2 list-of-pairs context)
      (cond ((null? list-of-pairs)
             (cond ((null? list-of-pairs) '())
                   ((any-good-fragments? (cue-part (car list-of-pairs)) sentence)
                    (helper2 (cdr (car list-of-pairs)) context))
                   (else (helper (cdr list-of-pairs)))))))
    <missing body>)
  (helper *weak-cues*))
```

Now it's clear that the body of `helper` is missing, after the inner definition of `helper2` you didn't write anything. Possibly you intended to call `helper2` at that point, but your code is confusing enough as it is and I can't guess what to write in the missing body, it's up to you.

Comment: @user2852171 you're welcome! if my answer was helpful for you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the check mark to its left ;)